# Core data sorting not working

Tags: sorting, core-data

I am trying to get a core data model sorted by `company` I am currently getting an error stating that I have an unknown receiver `device`. what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here is the error I am receiving:

[image]

Here is some code-

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];


    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    
    

    
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[
                                 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"company" ascending:YES]
                                 ];
    
    NSArray *sortedPeople = [self.devices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedPeople);
    



    
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: It would help if you included the error message.

Comment: `[Device sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...]` does not make any sense. What array do you want to sort? Perhaps `[self.devices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...]` ?

Comment: When I implement self.devices, it crashes when I load the app. Thoughts?

Comment: How is the Device entity defined? Does it have an attribute "company"? - What exception message do you get exactly?

Comment: Here is the exact error: Unknown receiver 'device', did you mean 'UIDevice'?

Comment: It would help if you describe your entities, attributes and relationships, and also what you want to achieve. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: You say "it crashes", but you need to provide some detail there. There's got to be an error message of some kind, and that message is a crucial detail.

Comment: @TomHarrington Please look above to see my edited post showing the error that I am receiving. It also highlights the 3rd from the bottom line of code that I included in my question; stating thread 1:breakpoint 1.1. Any ideas?

Comment: @PanicDev: There is no error message in the screen shot that you added! And it is still unclear what you want. You have fetched an array of "Device" objects and assigned it to `self.devices`. Is that what you want to sort? As I said `[Device sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...]` does not make any sense at all. Please provide enough information !!

Comment: Yes. I am trying to sort self.devices by a core data entry called 'company'. Sorry about my vague description of the error.

Comment: @MartinR Any thoughts on how I should go about fixing this issue?

Comment: @PanicDev: Now you use `[Self.device sorted...]` in your code, which is also wrong. It should be `[self.devices sorted...]`, as suggested above.

Comment: @MartinR Simple typo when editing the code on the form. What info do you need to know to help solve this problem?

Comment: The complete error message, for example, and the line where it occurs.

Comment: @MartinR I have posted the error message under Tom's answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems the line at fault is this one:

```
NSArray *sortedPeople = [Device sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

And the problem seems to be that `Device` is unknown to the compiler. In other words, you're saying that you want to sort something, but the compiler is unable to figure out what it is you want to sort.

It looks like `Device` is a Core Data entity type, but from your question I can't be sure if you actually have a class named `Device`. You used `@"Device"` in the fetch request, but the compiler doesn't try to resolve strings as symbols. So it's impossible to be certain of what you need to fix. Based on your description of what you're trying to do, you *probably* want to change that line to

```
NSArray *sortedPeople = [self.devices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

You also mentioned that you got crashes when doing that. But after much back and forth in comments you still haven't given any clue what error(s) or other messages you might be getting when the crash occurs. As a result, who knows? Maybe the `Device` entity doesn't have an attribute named `company`, and the sort fails because of that. Maybe something else. If you're unwilling to provide crucial details of your problem even after repeated requests, all anyone can do is try to guess.

Comment: What crucial details do you need? And how do I find the details that you need?

Comment: Both Martin and I have asked for details of the error that occurs when the app crashes. This is normally printed in Xcode's console. Martin also asked for information about your Core Data model, which you could get by looking at it.

Comment: I found this message in the console: 11/12/13 8:03:01.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF: 485440.862 AppleUSBEHCI::Found a transaction past the completion deadline on bus 0x24, timing out! (Addr: 7, EP: 1). Sorry it took so long for me to figure this out! Does this help?

Comment: That message appeared in Xcode? It doesn't look like anything remotely connected to your code.

Comment: The console was spitting out that message almost every second after the app crashed.

Comment: That would be extremely bizarre if true. Xcode prints messages to its console from, and about your app while it runs. It doesn't print anything when your app is not running, including after a crash. It's possible that you're looking in the Console app, which is completely the wrong place.

Comment: Oh whoops. I was. Where should I look to find the proper error message?

Comment: Xcode has a built-in console pane. @PanicDev, it seems like your biggest problem is lack of familiarity with your tools. I recommend Apple's **Xcode Core Concepts** video from WWDC 2013, which you can find at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: Ok, will do soon. I am pretty new to Xcode. Here is what I found in the console: 2013-11-13 07:46:23.189 Minutes[64146:a0b] (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x8d83f10> (entity: Device; id: 0x8d5e150 <x-coredata://29EA13EB-909E-46E8-B8FD-C71A9B6436CE/Device/p2> ; data: {\n    company = Reading;\n    name = 1;\n    version = \"Minutes of Harry Potter\";\n})", I had entered a sample value before I tried sorting, and it crashes trying to sort it. Where should I go from here?